# Why isn't conda updating even though it says a newer version is available?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update my (very old) conda version to the latest. However, when I run conda's suggested command, nothing happens:

```
$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.12.0
  latest version: 23.11.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.

$
```

How do I convince conda to update itself?

Comment: Can you try specifying the version explicitly? `conda install -n base -c defaults conda=23.11.0`. My guess is there's a conflict that conda isn't telling you about. Heh, I just saw in the deleted answer this same suggestion :-)